# MS SQL Server, selective backup tool

Tags: sql-server, backup

I'm looking for an enterprise tool / product - paid or free that is designed to handle selective backup / restore of massive MS SQL Server databases.

A simple usage scenario would be - from our prod database, to daily have a dev database restored with only a subset of data from Prod. This needs to be configured on a table by table basis. So certain tables can restore with more historic data than others, while some will just be completely excluded.

I'll be clear - what I don't want is a tool that does a complete backup, and then follows this up with truncate or delete commands.

I'm ideally looking for something defacto and industry standard tool, something that we can implement fairly easily and rollout across the board.

EDIT: I'm also thinking of just writing a custom tool which would use a series of inserts to get the job done, but I don't think this is the best / quickest way to do this, because performance is a major deciding factor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't happen.

Lets start- this is not an enterprise backup scenario, so there will not be an enterprise backup tool for that, simple like that.

Your usage is not an adminsitrative one but one that is common in testing and development - but only from those people that do not test on a full backup, which is quite useless (does not provide adequate performance metrics) and thus not an enterprise scenario.

Every enterprise scneario I know of loads a full backup into the non active database server (you have 2-3 fdatabase servers, just in case something happens).

MS SQL backup interface does not support selecting data below database level, to start with, so whatever you write will not be performant, sorry ;)